# What is the correct way to parent ImageBundles in the Bevy game engine so the child image doesn't alter the size of the parent image?

Tags: bevy

When I try to parent two ImageBundles together I don't get the expected result. The child image causes the parent image to resize to the size of the child image. I am trying to place the button image on top of the background image, but the following code places the button image on the background image and then scales the background image to the size of the button image.

If I comment out the push_children line of code then both images are displayed at the correct size.

```
   let ent1 = commands.spawn_bundle(ImageBundle {
       style: Style {
           align_self: AlignSelf::Center,
           ..Default::default()
       },
       material: materials.add(
           asset_server.load("Background.png").into()),
       transform: Transform::from_translation(Vec3::new(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
       ..Default::default()
   }).id();

   let ent2 = commands.spawn_bundle(ImageBundle {
       style: Style {
           align_self: AlignSelf::Center,
           ..Default::default()
       },
       material: materials.add(
           asset_server.load("button.png").into()),
       transform: Transform::from_translation(Vec3::new(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)),
       ..Default::default()
   }).id();

   commands.entity(ent1).push_children(&[ent2]);
```

Comment: I would expect this behaviour. If you want to scale the child image back up you can always do this (e.g. scale it relative to the scale of the parent).